# Representing as sum of squares of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Show that the polynomial $x^4y^2+y^4z^2+z^4x^2-3x^2y^2z^2$ cannot be written  as the  sum of squares of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ in $x, y, z$.

I could not make any progress/significant observation except for showing that the polynomial is always non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is similar to the case of the *Motzkin polynomial*

$$ x^4y^2 + x^2y^4 - 3x^2y^2 + 1,$$

which is non-negative over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and yet cannot be expressed as a sum of squares of real polynomials in $x$ and $y$. For references and proofs (e.g. by M. Marshall) see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial).

Comment: Sir, can you give an elementary proof of my problem? I am in high school and the problem is from E. J. Barbeau polynomials.

Comment: There is a high school proof available, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwjXy5bQjZLHAhVEkiwKHTHWAhY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucsd.edu%2F~njw%2FTeaching%2FMath271C%2FLecture_15.pdf&ei=bhfCVdfcDcSksgGxrIuwAQ&usg=AFQjCNE1HjOss0ajOBIkmOsSvWzZgx9TSQ&bvm=bv.99261572,d.bGg), for the polynomial $M(x,y,z)=x^4y^2+x^2y^4+z^6-3x^2y^2z^2$. Just do the same for your polynomial.